# FluentValidation 3: Error of WithMessage string formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, fluentvalidation

I use `FluentValidation 3` and I have a strange problem when I use overloaded WithMessage methods.

A composite format string are not formatting correct. I get "`true`" instead of `{0}` in my format string. All other format items are not replaced.

**For example:**

```
 public class MyModelValidator : AbstractValidator<MyModel>
    {
        public MyModelValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Caption).NotNull().WithMessage("{0} ----- {1}", "one", "two" );
        }
    }
```

Validation string which I get is: "`true----- {1}`" instead of "`one----- two`".

Could you explain me, what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Well, response is... in the source Code.

You use this overload (not really clear in its usage, I must say) of `WithMessage` :

```
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TProperty> WithMessage<T, TProperty>(this IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TProperty> rule, string errorMessage, params object[] formatArgs) {
    var funcs = ConvertArrayOfObjectsToArrayOfDelegates<T>(formatArgs);
    return rule.WithMessage(errorMessage, funcs);
    }
```

So "one" and "two" are changed to an array of  `Func<T, object>`, wich, of course, will lead to strange behaviours with your code...

You should use `string.Format` in your case

```
WithMessage(string.Format("{0} ----- {1}", "one", "two" ));
```

By the way, FluentValidation messages are "already preformatted" :
The goal to use `{0}` in WithMessage is to modifiy the text around `{0}`.
For example,  NotNull has a "1 argument" preformatted message.
That's why your `{0}` is transformed to "true", I think.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think the reason of problem is really "already preformatted" FluentValidation messages. Because when I pass to WithMessage array of func:

RuleFor(x => x.Caption).NotNull().WithMessage("{0} ----- {1}", x => "one", x => "two");

I have the same result. 

And I can't use string.Fotmat because I need pass as params exactly array of func.
So, it is impossible to create validation message dynamically?

Comment: Look here http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Localization&referringTitle=Documentation . You could use your own resx file, with notnull_error key accepting 2 properties. I suggest you to download source code to see the default Messages.resx file.